# Dependency was not found flip-toolkit

Tags: javascript, webpack, dependencies, webpack-encore

I want to use flip-toolkit (whitout react) so I do :

I followed the readme ->
https://github.com/aholachek/react-flip-toolkit

```
npm install flip-toolkit
then
import { Flipper } from 'flip-toolkit'
```

And i have this :

[terminal issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnrGo.png)

But i have both folders in my node_modules :

[folder flip-toolkit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mARld.png)

[folder react-flip-toolkit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nChds.png)

And here my file package.json :

[package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USBeF.png)

When I hovering 'flip-toolkit' i have that :

[path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJR0W.png)

I'm using Symfony 4.4 and bundle Webpack Encore for the assets.

Thanks for the help.

I also take a look at this post : [Webpack Encore: cannot import local dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48282613/webpack-encore-cannot-import-local-dependencies?rq=1)

Comment: How is this related to Symfony? What is "this problem"?

Comment: Hi Nero, could you please be so kind to inline the images for us? Thanks!

Comment: Hi guys, i update the post (cant post images needed at least 10 reputation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was a `bug`, if anyone have the same issue use `flip-toolkit@7.0.11`

[Here the issue on github](https://github.com/aholachek/react-flip-toolkit/issues/124)